# What's a good iOS app for quickly posting screenshots on the web?

Tags: ios, photos, screen-capture

Something analogous to photobucket for the desktop - whose iPhone app is a bit useless to me because it doesn't enable importing from the camera roll. I'm looking for something that easily allows me to share a screenshot (to embed somewhere, for example in a forum, or on a Stack Exchange question) but don't want to junk up my flickr, Instagram, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the official Flickr app. It supports uploading photos and videos from the Camera Roll. Flickr specifically will require that you already have an account on the service, most Twitter integrated networks (yFrog, TwitPic) will "create" an account when you use it for the first time.

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) the site.
[Flickr.app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flickr/id328407587?mt=8) the iOS app.

(Native to iPhone only, obviously works on the iPad using small screen emulation.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to "junk up" your flickr or instagram or whatever, you could just create another flickr or twitter account only for screenshots. Then you could use these specialized account settings in [Flickit](http://www.greenvolcanosoftware.com/flickit.html) or [Photoshop Express](http://www.photoshop.com/tools) or whatever.

You could also use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/anywhere). I love it for syncing files, and it easily works with images too.

Comment: Dropbox's Public Image Gallery is a pretty good idea. It's a bit indirect given how one uses the Dropbox iOS app, but a good idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have twitter, Echofon uploads pics from the camera roll to Twitpic very quickly. Otherwise, the Flickr iOS app works very well, and you can select any pic/screenshot from your library to upload. Thanks, Hope that helps.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to junk up my flickr, Instagram, etc. That goes for Twitter/Twitpic/whatever as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last part of the question (I'm posting from an iPhone). Can I suggest imageshack? If you already have that and want to keep it clean, then sorry again, but if not, They do a free app from which you can upload from camera roll.

Comment: Ditto. And I generally agree with Alistair's followup suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I like the ImgurFree app.  You can take a photo or import one from a Camera Roll.  It uploads the photo to imgur and creates a link that you can quickly copy the link in your clipboard or post directly to Reddit, or Email it.  Works great for me. It also keeps a history of all the images uploaded using the phone which you can quickly delete from Imgur site if you want.